# Python: Write dictionary lists with different indexes to CSV file

Tags: python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary of lists in which some lists only have one value while the others have many.

Using this code, I get the output I intend:

```
    import csv
    from collections import OrderedDict

    my_dict = OrderedDict()
    my_dict["Header1"] = [1,2,3]
    my_dict["Header2"] = [4,5,6]

    #if file doesn't exist...
    with open('mycsv.csv', 'wb') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
        w.writerow(my_dict.keys())
    with open('mycsv.csv', 'ab') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
        w.writerows(zip(*my_dict.values()))
```

Which will look somewhat like:

Header1;Header2

1;4

2;5

3;6

But in my case, when I have a dictionary of lists of this sort:

```
    my_dict["Header1"] = [1,2,3]
    my_dict["Header2"] = [4]
```

I get an output like:

Header1;Header2

1;4

When I intended to have:

Header1;Header2

1;4

2;

3;

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Thank you in advance (and sorry for any bad thread formatting,it's my first question here :P)!

Comment: Have you looked into [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)? `zip` will truncate all arguments down to the shortest length.

Comment: You can use `izip_longest` with a fillvalue of `''` - you might also wish to look at `csv.DictWriter` to automatically handle the header and avoid opening the file twice...

Comment: @jonrsharpe that worked just as I needed, thank you!

@JonClements I'm actually using `(if(os.path.isfile(...) == False): (...))` before the first file open so I only open the file twice if the file didn't exist already, but I'll look into that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map(lambda *x: tuple(x), *my_dict.values())` instead of `zip`. This will replace empty elements with `None`, or you can use `itertools.izip_longest(*my_dict.values())`. `csv` will automatically leave `None` values empty.